# ClassCastException on ArrayList's method "get"

Tags: java, android, arraylist, classcastexception

In the app control panel I found an error report that not only I can't reproduce, but also it make no sense to me.

This is the stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to ohm.quickdice.entity.RollResult[]
    at ohm.quickdice.activity.QuickDiceActivity.setupRollMenu(QuickDiceActivity.java:575)
    at ohm.quickdice.activity.QuickDiceActivity.onCreateContextMenu(QuickDiceActivity.java:459)
    at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:6229)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:81)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2292)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:564)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:564)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:564)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:564)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2772)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2717)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

An this is the code where the exception occour:

```
ArrayList<RollResult[]> resultList;
RollResult[] lastResult;

...

protected void setupRollMenu(int index, ContextMenu menu) {
    RollResult[] rollItem;
    RollResult[] nextItem;
    RollResult mergedRoll;

    if (index < 0) {
        rollItem = lastResult;
    } else {
        rollItem = resultList.get(index);
    }
    if (index + 1 < resultList.size()) {
        nextItem = resultList.get(index + 1); //This is row 575
    } else {
        nextItem = null;
    }
    ...
```

I wonder how the instruction "nextItem = resultList.get(int);" can raise this exception since resultList is defined as ArrayList and nextItem is an object of type RollResult[]...

It may depend on how Android serialize and deserialize instance state data to bundles?

Here how the serialization is done:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putSerializable(KEY_LAST_ROLL, lastResult);
    outState.putSerializable(KEY_ROLL_LIST, resultList);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and this is the deserialization:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Serializable tmp;
        tmp = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_LAST_ROLL);
        if (tmp instanceof RollResult[]) {
            lastResult = (RollResult[])tmp;
        }
        tmp = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_ROLL_LIST);
        if (tmp instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
            resultList = (ArrayList<RollResult[]>)tmp;
        }
    }

    if (lastResult == null) {
        lastResult = new RollResult[0];
    }

    if (resultList == null) {
        resultList = new ArrayList<RollResult[]>();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Was the code trying to read serialized data from an older version (which wrote Object arrays instead of properly typed ones)?

Comment: Generics are only a compile-time thing. If an `Object` is being added to the `ArrayList` at runtime through reflection, unsafe casting or maybe (though I'm not sure on this) deserialization, the error will not be noticed until you try to assign that `Object` to a reference of the type it's supposed to be. If you can't reproduce it, maybe an old version stored an incorrect `ArrayList` on their end.

Comment: The serialization is made only on the same session so I don't think it is possible that serialization and deserialization are made by different app version.